# Add div container around images and center

Tags: html, css

I am working on a website, and I would like to align 4 circles in the center of the content area. The example can be found at invisionbilling.com/stackoverflow. I have something right now that does the job, but I know there will be issues with different window sizes, different picture sizes, etc. How do I set the height of the div container to automatically wrap around the 4 circles/images? Is there a way to automatically center it using margin-left and margin-right? I tried "auto" for all of these and it wasn't doing the job. Thanks!

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="circles">
<img src="http://invisionbilling.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/Benefits- 
Circles-Lower-Costs-300x300.png" alt="" width="150" height="150" 
class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-358" />
</div>

<div class="circles">
<img src="http://invisionbilling.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/Benefits- 
Circles-Greater-Cash-Flow-300x300.png" alt="" width="150" height="150" 
class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-363" />
</div>

<div class="circles">
<img src="http://invisionbilling.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/Benefits- 
Circles-Increased-Revenue-300x300.png" alt="" width="150" height="150" 
class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-364" />
</div>

<div class="circles">
<img src="http://invisionbilling.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/Benefits- 
Circles-Emphasis-on-Patient-Care-300x300.png" alt="" width="150" 
height="150" class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-361" />
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.circles {
    display: block !important;
    float: left !important;
    margin: 10px !important;
}

.wrapper {
    height: 175px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 225px;
 }
```

Comment: If you have the flexibility in your project to not re-invent the wheel, get Bootstrap 4.  You'll be able to manage much of your height wrapping issues simply by tapping into their utilities and components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try flexbox instead of floating, and try never to use !important:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .circles {
            margin: 10px;
        }

        .wrapper {
            height: 175px;
            width: 100%;
            margin: auto;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="circles">
        <img src="http://invisionbilling.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/Benefits-Circles-Lower-Costs-300x300.png" alt="" width="150" height="150" 
        class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-358" />
        </div>

        <div class="circles">
        <img src="http://invisionbilling.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/Benefits-Circles-Greater-Cash-Flow-300x300.png" alt="" width="150" height="150" 
        class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-363" />
        </div>

        <div class="circles">
        <img src="http://invisionbilling.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/Benefits-Circles-Increased-Revenue-300x300.png" alt="" width="150" height="150" 
        class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-364" />
        </div>

        <div class="circles">
        <img src="http://invisionbilling.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/Benefits-Circles-Emphasis-on-Patient-Care-300x300.png" alt="" width="150" 
        height="150" class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-361" />
        </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Othmane! That flexbox appears to be doing the job. I also removed "important" and I will keep your suggestion in mind going forward.